# In xonsh how can I receive from a pipe to a python expression?

Tags: python, bash, xonsh

In the [`xonsh`](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/) shell how can I receive from a pipe to a python expression? Example with a `find` command as pipe provider:

```
find $WORKON_HOME -name pyvenv.cfg -print | for p in <stdin>: $(ls -dl @(p))
```

The `for p in <stdin>:` is obviously pseudo code. What do I have to replace it with?

Note: In bash I would use a  construct like this:

```
... | while read p; do ... done
```

Comment: why do you have the question tagged with `bash` if you ask for specifics about `xonch` ?

Comment: @Aserre Because it is related to `bash`: I want to translate a `bash` construct into `xonsh` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to pipe input into a Python expression is to use a function that is a [callable alias](https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#callable-aliases), which happens to accept a stdin file-like object. For example,

```
def func(args, stdin=None):
    for line in stdin:
        ls -dl @(line.strip())

find $WORKON_HOME -name pyvenv.cfg -print | @(func)
```

Of course you could skip the `@(func)` by putting func in `aliases`,

```
aliases['myls'] = func
find $WORKON_HOME -name pyvenv.cfg -print | myls
```

Or if all you wanted to do was iterate over the output of `find`, you don't even need to pipe.

```
for line in !(find $WORKON_HOME -name pyvenv.cfg -print):
    ls -dl @(line.strip())
```

Comment: Thx. Makes all sense. Just a big shame, that there is no way write python code to receive the pipe on the same line where the pipe is...

Comment: If the expression is suitably small, it can fit in a lambda in the `@(lambda args, stdin: ...)`.  Also always happy to have discussions of new syntax at https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues :)

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out the lambda expression for this case. I tried ...`| @(lambda args, stdin: [ $[ls -dl @(l.strip())] for l in stdin ])])` and I get the first `ls` line printed  (so the lambda expression must have been accepted), but then a "TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)".

Comment: Something like `lambda args, stdin: ''.join([$(ls -l @(line.strip())) for line in stdin])` should work, but I am getting a similar odd error.  Can you please open at issue? Thanks!

Comment: `@()` executes python or xonsh code? How can a python function `func` use a shell syntax? Sorry I am new to xonch and trying to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on the answer from [Anthony Scopatz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312428/anthony-scopatz) you can do this on one line with a [callable alias](https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#callable-aliases) as a lambda. The function takes the third form, `def mycmd2(args, stdin=None)`. I discarded `args` with `_` because I don't need it and shortened `stdin` to `s` for convenience. Here is a command to hash a file:

```
type image.qcow2 | @(lambda _,s: hashlib.sha256(s.read()).hexdigest())
```